# How to generate maven site automatically during a build

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-site-plugin

I know I can call `mvn site-deploy` individually, but how can I kick off a site deploy during a build of `mvn clean deploy`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `site` plugin to the pom's `<build>` with an appropriate goal to run during a phase of your choice.

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>site deploy</id>
      <phase>your_choice_of_phase</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>site</goal>
        <goal>deploy</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: you're close, but 'site-deploy' is a phase, not a goal. your pom should call the site goal then deploy goal separately.

Comment: @mystarrocks Thanks for the answer. Is there any advantage of doing it this way over adding the phase to the mvn command like `maven clean install site-deploy`?

Comment: @yellavon I don't see any advantage myself. Of course, forcing it to happen as part of the build ensures the site deployment is attempted always in the specified phase, regardless of the who builds it or what commands they pass in. Not sure if I can call it an advantage, though.